# handler fails after upgrading from jQuery 1.8 to 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app I have the following code that displays a spinner while an AJAX request is in progress:

```
$("#spinner")
    .on("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('fast');
    })
    .on("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

After upgrading from jQuery 1.8 to 1.10 this no longer works. I don't think it's because one of the functions I'm using has been removed, because there are no errors in the Firebug console.

Comment: @mplungjan won't this only tell me about functions I'm using that have been removed? I'm pretty sure I'm not calling any removed functions, bcause I would see an error in Firebug in that case

Comment: Right. See Liam's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres your problem I reckon, says this in the documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSend() method should only be attached to
>   document.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Comment: The docs say the change was made in version 1.8, but this worked fine in 1.8.3

Comment: You're still using it wrong though? Jquery could of beefed up this requirement.

Comment: "could of"? you mean "could have", right? Is that a scouse expression?

Comment: @mplungjan Nothern, I'm actually welsh... :)

Comment: Today I Learned: Dutch people speak better English than the Welsh. Luckily nobody noticed you incorrectly using "wrong" instead of "wrongly"

Comment: I am Danish and was told by a guy at Forest Gate in London: "You speak better English than what I do" ;))

Comment: Personally I believe Grammar is an outdated Victorian concept, when there was an attempt to unify the entire "empire" under a common language structure. Language has always evolved and regional dialects are just as valid as the accepted, generally southern, ideal....But I dont's speak proper you see's....

Comment: I work with huge search engines and rely on syntax so I am a stickler for correct language :)